# Idiomatic Way of Traversing Image, Functionally

Tags: java, image, multidimensional-array, functional-programming, java-8

I'm using Java 8 and trying to write pure functional code. In my latest project, I need to step through every pixel in an image and perform some computation on every pixel. The code I came up with goes something like this:

```
IntStream
        .range(0, newImage.getWidth())
        .forEach(i -> IntStream
                .range(0, newImage.getHeight())
                .forEach(n -> {
                    inspectPixel(i, n, newImage);
                })
        );
```

However, the imperative version goes something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newImage.getWidth(); i++){
    for (int n = 0; n < newImage.getHeight(); n++){
        inspectPixel(i, n, newImage);
    }
}
```

Maybe this is just because I'm too used to imperative programming, but the latter seems more readable than the former. One of two things is going on:

1. My code is wrong, am I going about this the wrong way? If so, what *should* the code look like? How do you functionally traverse any two dimensional data structure, not just an image?
2. This actually is the best version of the program in a functional way for Java 8, and this situation is simply poor for functional programming.

Comment: `My code is wrong` How is your code wrong? Does it not work? If it doesn't work, what's the problem?

Comment: Wrong as in not efficient or idiomatic @vincemigh

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. A simpler interface to use? As in you're asking if Java has functional support for scanning the pixels of an image? Please be more clear, your question currently seems like a "how can I improve my code" post. How could you possibly know you are wrong if you aren't sure what's right? For all you know, you could be doing it the best way. If you're asking if the JDK comes with an api for easily scanning pixels in images, you should put that in your answer. You could always create your own interface to lower the verbosity of the second version.

Comment: The best way would be to iterate over pixels instead of coordinates. If the API doesn't support this then implement your own iterator. The same is true for any other n-dimensional data structure.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `IntStream` was not specifically targeted towards iterating over pixels. The verbosity is a sacrifice for the power of the stream. Although functional, it's purpose does not fit your needs.

You could always create your own interface to handle the messy work:

```
class PixelScanner {
    public static void scan(BufferedImage image, PixelInspector inspector) {
        int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                int pixel = pixels[x + y * image.getWidth()];
                inspector.inspect(pixel);
            }
        }
    }
}

interface PixelInspector {
    void inspect(int pixel);
}
```

Which you can then use as:

```
PixelScanner.scan(image, pixel -> {
    // inspect pixel
});
```

Could even add more parameters to inspect, such as which (x, y) position that pixel is in. You could even wrap each pixel to pass more data about it to the inspector. I also suggest making `scan` non-static and using a `PixelScanner` object instead. Functional programming is useful, but OOP definitely has it's spotlight moments, and both should be used effectively.

Comment: Doesn't `for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) ...` break the functional style? I'm trying to traverse the image functionally; how could that be done? I like the second part of the program, however. As in `PixelScanner.scan(image, pixel -> {})` that has a nice flow to it

Comment: @Michael Functions must have implementation. It cannot be functions all the way down to the core. Even `forEach` uses such techniques (for example, the `ArrayList#forEach` implementation, which uses a simple indexed loop. `LinkedList` uses an enhanced loop, which is syntactic sugar for using an `Iterator` with a loop). This simply covers up the verbosity, as any interface would. You must iterate through the pixels somehow. The JDK does not seem to have it's own API for this, but if it did, it would most likely do something very similar at it's core

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, and by wrong I mean fundamentally wrong, not stylistically. Though, it is the result of a bad coding style. You should give variables meaningful names. Names like `i` and `n` are not appropriate for variables actually holding `x` and `y` coordinates. Had you given them the names `x` and `y`, you noticed the problem immediately, I think:

```
IntStream
        .range(0, newImage.getWidth())
        .forEach(x -> IntStream
                .range(x, newImage.getHeight())
                .forEach(y -> {
                    inspectPixel(x, y, newImage);
                })
        );
```

Obviously, `range(x, newImage.getHeight())` can’t be right…

That said, nested `forEach` calls are indeed usually a sign for a transformation of imperative code that most likely should stay imperative if you don’t find a better solution.

Since you want to process pixels individually, you can use `flatMap` to produce a stream of coordinates, but you need a type to hold these as elements of the resulting stream, e.g.

```
IntStream.range(0, newImage.getWidth()).boxed()
    .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0, newImage.getHeight()).mapToObj(y -> new Point(x, y)))
    .forEach(point -> inspectPixel(point.x, point.y, newImage));
```

Here, we are holding the coordinates in point instances. Unfortunately we have to box the `x` coordinates here, because `IntStream` doesn’t offer a `flatMapToObj` operation.

If the object creation bothers you, you may replace the point instance with a packed `long`, which also allows the `x` values to be processed as primitive data types, but, of course, it doesn’t add to the readablility:

```
LongStream.range(0, newImage.getWidth())
    .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0, newImage.getHeight()).mapToLong(y -> (long)x<<32|y))
    .forEach(point -> inspectPixel((int)(point>>>32), (int)point, newImage));
```

Of course, if you are interested in the pixel data only and the `x` and `y` values are only there to help you to access them, you could stream over the pixels in the first place instead:

```
Arrays.stream(newImage.getRGB(0, 0, newImage.getWidth(), newImage.getHeight(),
                              null, 0, newImage.getWidth()))
      .forEach(argb -> inspectPixel(argb)));
```